# Re-typecasting a variable, possible?

Tags: c, gcc, casting

Is it possible to recast the a variable permanently, or have a wrapper function such that the variable would behave like another type?

I would want to achieve something I posted in the other question:
[Typecasting variable with another typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579592/typecasting-variable-with-another-typedef)

**Update:** Added GCC as compiler. May have a extension that would help?

Comment: Do types have "behavior" in C? I don't really understand the question.

Comment: What do you mean by recasting a variable **permenently**?

Comment: Sorry I knew that the question is a bit vague, I'm trying to clarify as I go on

Comment: Are you trying to change the type of a variable? Or reinterpret a variable's data as another type? One of these things is possible, doable, and sane...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can cast a variable from one type to another:

```
 int x = 5;
 double y = (double) x; // <== this is what a cast looks like
```

However, you cannot modify the type of the identifier 'x' in-place, if that is what you are asking. Close to that, though, you can introduce another scope with that identifier redeclared with some new type:

```
  int x = 5;
  double y = (double) x;
  {
      double x = y; // NOTE: this isn't the same as the 'x' identifier above
      // ...
  }
  // NOTE: the symbol 'x' reverts to its previous meaning here.
```

Another thing you could do, though it is really a horrible, horrible idea is:

```
  int x = 5;
  double new_version_of_x = (double) x;  // Let's make 'x' mean this
  #define x new_version_of_x
  // The line above is pure evil, don't actually do it, but yes,
  // all lines after this one will think 'x' has type double instead
  // of int, because the text 'x' has been rewritten to refer to
  // 'new_version_of_x'. This will likely lead to all sorts of havoc
```

Answer (score 1):

You accomplish that by casting then assigning.

```
int f(void * p) {
  int * i;

  i = (int *)p;

  //lots of code here with the i pointer, and every line
  //really thinks that it is an int pointer and will treat it as such
}
```

**EDIT** From the other question you linked:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned char a;
  unsigned char b; 
  unsigned char c;
} type_a;

typedef struct {
 unsigned char e;
 unsigned char f[2];
} type_b;

//initialize type a
type_a sample;
sample.a = 1;
sample.b = 2;
sample.c = 3;
```

Now `sample` is initialized, but you want to **access** it differently, you want to **pretend** that in fact that variable has another type, so you declare a pointer to the type you want to "disguise" `sample` as:

```
type_b * not_really_b;
not_really_b = (type_b*)&sample;
```

See, that is the whole magic.

`not_really_b->e` is equal 1

`not_really_b->f[0]` is equal 2

`not_really_b->f[1]` is equal 3

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Those `struct`s are declared incorrectly. Commas are for `enum`s, `union`s and `struct`s use semicolons to separate their fields.

Comment: I just copy and pasted from the other question, let me sanitize that

Comment: +1 for actually reading what the OP wants and giving a working answer :-)  Though you might want to point out that such type punning usually means terribly bad luck. Such hacks work fine a thousand times until the day they fail for some non-obvious reason. One day you'll do that with a struct that contains types with a certain padding/alignment, or you'll use the wrong order without noticing. Alone at home, this will mean you spend your weekend wasting your time, figuring out why your program crashes. At work, in a team, you risk that other people throw heavy things at you. Or worse.

Comment: @Damon I completely agree with you, this is bad practice unless it is very controlled. I've done it before where I had this list that could store different types of structs, but every struct had a common header, containing the "next" pointer, so I could almost safely typecast any of the structs to the "header struct" and transverse it, but then again, it is not 100% safe

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are better (declare a variable of the type you want, and do an assignment).  If that's not what you're asking for, you could use a macro:

```
long i;
#define i_as_int ((int)i)

printf( "i = %ld\n", i);
printf( "i = %d\n", i_as_int);
```

But wouldn't it be clearer to just say `(int) i` if that's what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

```
As long as you realize in C pointers are nothing but addresses of memory 
locations of certain types, you should have your answer. For example the
following program will print the name of the file

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *i;
    i = (int *) argv[0];
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("%s\n", ((char *) i));
}
```