# Extraneous (void *) in: type_a sample; type_b *sample_b = (type_b *) ((void*) &sample);

Tags: c

I was reading this thread: [Typecasting variable with another typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579592/typecasting-variable-with-another-typedef)

`type_b *sample_b = (type_b *) ((void *) &sample);`

Isn't (void *) extraneous? &sample would return a pointer of type: type_a, which can be cast directly to (type_b *). Why the extra (void *)? I feel it's wrong, but am not confident enough in my C - hence the extra verification.

Comment: It's about standard compliance. You're not technically allowed to cast one pointer to another, but you *are* allowed to cast to and from `void*`.

Comment: It would take very little effort to try both methods out, see whether the differ, then ask whether this is e.g. a portability issue, which I think it probably is.

Comment: I hate `void*` in this case... never heard of any special case that there have to be a `void*` in a type cast. Could anyone here give an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting the pointer to type `void` hides the pointer's true type from the compiler so you can cast it to whatever different type you want and the compiler will not have enough information to know if it's valid or not, thus it will allow it.

Without doing this, the compiler will - at a minumum - complain that you are trying to cast a pointer from one type to another incompatible type.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

The original poster of the question you referenced is trying to do something dangerous. The assumption is the alignment of the structures in memory will be the same, allowing them to access the two individual char's as if they were a single array of two chars. This may be true in theory and will probably work in a small test program, but if this is done in a piece of production code, *it will absolutely end in tears and gnashing of teeth at 3am.*

Comment: Thanks guys! This place rocks! I liked all answers but I'll go with this one because I can't select more than one :)

Answer (score 2):

GCC has the ability to optimize code based on the fact that it detects that two pointers that point to incompatible types point to the same memory location. Using both pointers to access the value will give a warning about an aliasing violation then ("type punning").

Sometimes, if you put a `(void*)` cast in between the one cast operands, before casting to the other point type, [will silence false positive warnings](http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/tools-gcc/2005-August/000048.html) in cases where you can legally do such an overlapping access.